# Creating and Accessing Abstract Class Fields in Scala

Tags: scala, class, abstract-class

I'm new to Scala and am really having some difficulty with some fairly simple problems. I'm implementing a simple binary tree to store integers as follows:

```
abstract class IntSet {
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean
}

class Empty extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = new NonEmpty(x, new Empty, new Empty)
}

class NonEmpty(elem: Int, left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
  val head = elem
  val leftChild = left
  val rightChild = right

  def contains(x: Int): Boolean =
    if (x < elem) left contains x
    else if (x > elem) right contains x
    else true

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet =
    if (x < elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left incl x, right)
    else if (x > elem) new NonEmpty(elem, left, right incl x)
    else this
}

val my_intset = new NonEmpty(5, new Empty, new Empty)
my_intset.head
val new_intset = my_intset.incl(10)
new_intset.head
```

And run into two problems: Firstly, I was unable to access any of the elements of these classes and so implemented the fields `head`, `leftchild`, and `rightchild`. Which makes them accessible for `my_intset`. However, once `incl` is called, the type of the object changes and `new_intset` is now an `IntSet`, leaving me unable to access the elements within again. How am I to ensure such fields are accessible at all times?

Secondly, I'm uncomfortable that the type of object changes with the call to `incl`. From a user point of view I feel that both these objects are instances of `IntSet`, that's my intent anyway. I am right to be concerned? Is there a way to control this behaviour?

Answer (score 2):

In Scala, one can leverage [Abstract Data Types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_data_type) and [Pattern Matching](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/pattern-matching.html) to operate on such types.

We can modify your example a little. We'll create a `sealed trait` which defines the basic structure for the types:

```
sealed trait IntSet {
  val head: Option[Int]
  val left: IntSet
  val right: IntSet

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean
}
```

And now we'll add concrete case objects/classes that inherit:

```
case class NonEmpty(head: Option[Int], left: IntSet, right: IntSet) extends IntSet {
  def contains(x: Int): Boolean = {
    if (x < head.getOrElse(0)) left contains x
    else if (x > head.getOrElse(0)) right contains x
    else true
  }

  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = {
    if (x < head.getOrElse(0)) NonEmpty(head, left incl x, right)
    else if (x > head.getOrElse(0)) NonEmpty(head, left, right incl x)
    else this
  }
}

case object Empty extends IntSet {
  override val head: Option[Int] = None
  override val left: IntSet = Empty
  override val right: IntSet = Empty

  def contains(x: Int): Boolean = false
  def incl(x: Int): IntSet = NonEmpty(Some(x), Empty, Empty)
}
```

Note how `Empty` is a `case object`. As all empty `IntSet`s are the same, we only need a single representation of one, we don't need to allocate instances of it. Also note how we use it to represent our `left` and `right` values.

Now, going back to your original example, this should work fine:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val myIntSet = new NonEmpty(Some(5), Empty, Empty)
  println(myIntSet.head)
  val newIntSet = myIntSet.incl(10)
  println(newIntSet.right.head)
}
```

Also, when we want to operate on an `IntSet` we can pattern match on it to work with the underlying concrete type:

```
def isEmpty(intSet: IntSet): Boolean = intSet match {
  case Empty => true
  case NonEmpty(_, _, _) => false
}
```

As a side note, I used an `Option[Int]` to represent the `head`. If you don't mind making `head` of `Empty` the value 0 instead, you can use an `Int`.

If you want a similar example to yours, I suggest [looking at the implementation for `List[+A]`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala)

---

An additional example where the algebra only defines the types you operate on can look like this:

```
sealed trait BinaryTree
case class Node(value: Int, left: BinaryTree, right: BinaryTree) extends BinaryTree
case object Empty extends BinaryTree

def incl(tree: BinaryTree, x: Int): BinaryTree = {
  tree match {
    case Node(value, left, right) =>
      if (x < value) Node(value, incl(left, x), right)
      else if (x > value) Node(value, left, incl(right, x))
      else tree
    case Empty => Node(x, Empty, Empty)
  }
}
```

And now:

```
def main (args: Array[String] ): Unit = {
  val n = Node(0, Node(1, Empty, Empty), Node(2, Empty, Empty))
  val x = incl(n, 3)
  println(x)
}
```

Yields:

```
Node(0,Node(1,Empty,Empty),Node(2,Empty,Node(3,Empty,Empty)))
```